# Determine a function to extract the individual digits of a long data type without using arrays and use only loops or conditionals

Tags: c

I am trying to determine a function to extract the individual digits of a long data type which the user enters.

```
int remain(int digit)
{
    while(number != 0)
    {
        digit = number % 10;
        number = number / 10;
    }
    return digit;
}
```

In this code the `number` variable is the number entered by user.

I want to extract all the digits of the number (e.g. a 16 digit number). So when I print `remain(16)` it prints 16 instead of 16th digit or prints 1 if I print `remain(1)`. And also it prints the first digit if the number is less than 13 or greater than 16 and prints the 1 or 2 or 3 if i print `remain(1)` or `remain(2)` or `remain(3)` instead of printing the 1st or 2nd or 3rd digit, if the number is 13 digit long or 16 digit long or 15 digit long.

Comment: What part are you stuck on? If you want to return more than a single digit, then your function will need to return a character array containing the extracted digits (and also a nul-terminating character if you want to use the return as a string). Is that what you want to do?

Comment: To me it's unclear what you want the function to do. Can you add some better example. For instance like: if `number` is `31415926535` what do you expect when calling `remain(1)` ? what do you expect when calling `remain(3)` ? what do you expect when calling `remain(5)` ? what do you expect when calling `remain(0)` ? what do you expect when calling `remain(23)` ?

Comment: Would you mind to show us some examples? From the long sentences I don't grasp what you want. Please [edit] your question with a few inputs, the expected output and with the output you get instead. A [example] would be the optimum.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after your edit, I understand you want to print the return of the function and have all digits print. While you can simply use `printf()`, extracting with `%` and `/` is another way to extract digits. But, as you have found, when you extract digits with `%` and `/`, the digits will end up in reverse order. The solve that problem, you simply fill an array with digits, working from the end of the array back to the beginning.

Now before looking at a solution, if you want to `"... extract the individual digits of a long data..."` -- you will need to change the type in your function from `int` to `long` or you will experience a mismatch of type-size on systems where `int` and `long` are different sizes (like on x86_64).

In order for the array to survive the return of your function, you can either pass in an array to fill using another parameter, or you can declare your array with `static` storage duration so it survives return (but not that make the function not thread_safe in multithreaded programs -- not a concern here)

You can do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NCHR 32         /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define BASE 10

char *extract_digits (long n)
{
    static char digits[NCHR];           /* static, so digits survives return */
    char *p = digits + NCHR - 1;        /* pointer to last char in digits */
    int sign = n < 0;                   /* check sign of n (negative, sign == 1) */
    
    if (sign)                           /* process positive number */
        n = -n;
    
    if (!n) {                           /* handle zero case, sign irrelevant */
        *--p = '0';
        return p;
    }
    
    do {                                /* convert each digit to char */
        *--p = n % BASE + '0';          /* fill from end of digits array */
        n /= BASE;
    } while (n);
    
    if (sign)                           /* if sign, add '-' at front */
        *--p = '-';
    
    return p;                           /* return ptr to start of digits in digits[] */
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    long v = argc > 1 ? strtol(argv[1], NULL, BASE) : -2381;
    
    printf ("digits: %s\n", extract_digits(v));
}
```

(**note:** I have change the function name to `extract_digits()`, you can rename it as you please)

The program prints the extracted digits directly using the function return -- which is what I take was your intent from the question.

**Example Use/Output**

Using default value:

```
$ ./bin/extractdigits_fnc
digits: -2381
```

Passing value:

```
$ ./bin/extractdigits_fnc 54823
digits: 54823
```

Passing zero:

```
$ ./bin/extractdigits_fnc 0
digits: 0
```

Passing negative zero:

```
$ ./bin/extractdigits_fnc -0
digits: 0
```

Your '16' example:

```
$ ./bin/extractdigits_fnc 16
digits: 16
```

Look things over and let me know if I understood your question correctly.

Comment: No, i am trying to implement a program in which the digits extracted from the long is used individually for other calculations. Like i want to multiply the 1st 3rd 5th 7th digit by 2 and add the digits of the products (not the product itself) and add it to the remaining digits

Comment: Okay, now I understand. I'll have time in a bit to update the answer. How will you know which digits (1, 3, 5, ..) are they always the odd digits? And how do we know what the multiplier is? Is it always 2? Can we add more parameters to the function? Like `remains (value, which, multiplier)`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a function that can extract the n'th digit in a number, it can be something like:

```
int extract_digit(unsigned long long number, unsigned digit)
{
    int res = -1;
    if (digit > 0)
    {
        unsigned count = 1;
        unsigned long long tmp = number;
        while(tmp/10 > 0)
        {
            ++count;
            tmp /= 10;
        }
    
        if (digit <= count)
        {
            tmp = number;
            while ((count - digit) > 0)
            {
                --count;
                tmp /= 10;
            }
    
            res = tmp % 10;
        }
    }
    
    return res;
}
```

Notice that the function assumes that the left-most digit is digit 1.

The function will return a `-1` if the requested "digit" doesn't exists. Otherwise the function returns the digit.

The function can be used like:

```
int main(void){
    
    unsigned long long number = 31415926535ULL;
    
    printf("number: %llu\n", number);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 13; ++i)
    {
        int n = extract_digit(number, i);  // Get i'th digit
        if (n < 0)
        {
            printf("Digit %u is out of range\n", i);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Digit %u is %d\n", i, n);
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
number: 31415926535
Digit 0 is out of range
Digit 1 is 3
Digit 2 is 1
Digit 3 is 4
Digit 4 is 1
Digit 5 is 5
Digit 6 is 9
Digit 7 is 2
Digit 8 is 6
Digit 9 is 5
Digit 10 is 3
Digit 11 is 5
Digit 12 is out of range
```